# How can I align elements to the left and right in the same line without floats?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am trying to align two inline elements, one to the left and one to the right. I'd like to accomplish this without using floats.

In my case, I have a h1, with a span and a link. I'd like the span to align to the left and the link to align to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkfacta3/

```css
h1>span {
  text-align: left;
}
h1>a {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
 <h1><span>Align me left</span> <a href="">align me right</a></h1>
```

This is the desired result:

[image: desired-result]

Comment: A bit of history: The birth to this question is because the behavior of floats is wild. Even with clears and enveloped DIV's the results of floats vary widely between browsers and turns an EZ css task into a nightmare trying to control weird and unexpected behaviors among browsers. Even with CSS v3.0, these unwanted behaviors prevailed; forcing me to avoid floats like a plague and favor alternatives. It is thanks to this search that I've found better and cleaner ways to CSS a page WITHOUT floats. Eliminating the need for clears and unecessary extra HTML elements. JUST BETTER!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use some flexbox magic:

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Align me left</span>
  <a href="">align me right</a>
</h1>
```

Comment: this works but i get a weird margin above the h1, even after taking off margins

Comment: @chovy That is not related to flexbox. It might be the margin of `h1` or `body`.

Comment: if i remove `display: flex` it goes away. I think it was my fixed width causing the issue though.

Comment: This is very good and working answer. Thank you! For my case I used 'div' instead of 'h1' and it is working fine. I found more info about the css flex here -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Comment: Nice solution! Works like a charm

Answer (score 11):

You can use CSS `display:table` + `display:table-cell`.

```css
h1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
h1>span {
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
}
h1>a {
  text-align: right;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Align me left</span><a href="#">align me right</a></h1>
```

Or, do it with `display:inline-block`.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 0; /* remove whitespace */
}
h1>span,
h1>a {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
h1>span {
  text-align: left;
}
h1>a {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Align me left</span><a href="#">align me right</a></h1>
```

Note, either way above will make the `<a>` clickable area larger, wrap it into another `<span>` if you need to correct that.

Comment: The `display: inline-block;` solution worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try CSS tables, and take some precaution for dealing with the link if you want the active area to extend only over the text.

Depending on how you want this to work in a flexible design, floats might be a  feasible option.

```css
h1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 span, h1 a {
  display: table-cell;
}
h1 span {
  text-align: left;
}
h1 a {
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Align me left</span> <a href="">align me right</a></h1>
```