# Align one of three elements right

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment

My question is a bit like this one: [CSS: alight left and right within the same line (without floats)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572539/css-alight-left-and-right-within-the-same-line-without-floats)
The difference is that i have 3 elements in a row (date, title, author) and I want the author to be aligned right.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtqkm2sk/2/) with a part of the solution.
The problem is, that in my fiddle the author is positioned absolutely, so while making the window smaller you'll see that at some point the title will overlap the author.

```
.e-author {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

**TL;DR:** Can I align one of three elements at the very right without floats and / or additional html elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flexbox for this.

Set `display:flex` on your `<li>` and a `margin-left: auto` on the `.e-author`.

Here's an update to your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dtqkm2sk/3/

Zoe Gillenwater has a very insightful [talk on CSS Flexbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe1YpKpwISs) which covers this and many other use cases.

Comment: thanks, I always wanted to use flex for something but never found a use-case. Maybe because I don't really know how powerful it is

Comment: You're welcome. Here's a collection of common use cases for CSS Flexbox: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/